# Return value from object literal patern

Tags: javascript, return-value, object-literal

Hi guys wondering if someone can help me, I am using the object literal pattern to organise my code (I'm new to this pattern). I am trying to return the value of a variable from a function but it keeps returning me the whole function - could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here is a snippet from my code -

```
    'teamStatusTableHeight': function() {
    var theHeight = $(".teamStatusTable").height() - 130;
    return theHeight;
},
'numOfTeamMembers': function() {
    var numTeams = $(".teamStatusTable tr").length;
    return numTeams
} ,
'scrollDistance': function() {
    var scroll = teamStatus.teamStatusTableHeight / teamStatus.numOfTeamMembers + 30;
    return scroll;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: 'scrollDistance': function() {
  var scroll = teamStatus.teamStatusTableHeight / teamStatus.numOfTeamMembers + 30;
  return scroll;
 },

Comment: I use the values above to try and calcualte a figure - i would call the function live modulename.scrollDistance();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* those functions, like this:

```
var scroll = teamStatus.teamStatusTableHeight() / teamStatus.numOfTeamMembers() + 30;
```

Note the added `()` so you're using the *result* of the functions, not the functions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine to me.  Perhaps you are not actually calling the function?

```
// get the function
MyObj.teamStatusTableHeight

// run the function
MyObj.teamStatusTableHeight()
```

Did you leave off the parentheses?  They are required to actually execute the function.  Otherwise they simply provide access to the function object itself.

Comment: Hi thanks you were correct I marked nicks question as resolved as he posted first - but thanks for your help :-)